# ¿Cómo mantengo el alcance de una clase SQLAlchemy de Flask en una ruta nueva?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

No sé si lo que tengo que hacer es manejarme únicamente por consultas a la base de datos o puedo oportunamente usar el ORM con el fin de usar el mismo registro instanciado anteriormente pero en una nueva página de la red.

ejemplo:

```
@app.route("/posts_view/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def posts_view():
    posts = Game.get_all()
    post = ""
    clase = ORM_Class(argumentos)
    return render_template("posts_view.html", posts=posts, post=post)

@app.route("/post/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def posts_view():
    return render_template("post.html", clase=clase)
```

En caso que la idea fuere usarlo a través de consultas me dedico a ello, pero por el momento no sabría cómo proseguir. Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea es consultar la base de datos con SQLAlchemy. con

```
class = ORM_Class.query.filter_by(the_camp=the_data).first()
```